# How to detect that input is coming from IME in TextBox in UWP?

Tags: xaml, uwp, textbox, cjk, ime

I am working on input text validation for an application in UWP. I am using a textbox for user input. Based on the letter inserted, I remove character if its a special character (%, $, ..) when text changing and fix the position of cursor by `TextBoxName.SelectionStart`. But in Korean language when input is from IME by pressing right control, my fixing cursor position using `TextBoxName.SelectionStart` is not working. It always moves cursor one position right that I set during TextChanging Event.

So, I want to know wheather the input is coming from IME (Pop up in the Image) or not?
[image]

Comment: In general it is better to simply *detect*, not *correct*, any invalid input from the user. Dynamically editing text just gets messy, especially with things like the clipboard or IMEs. You can *detect* bad characters dynamically and show some visual feedback (eg, a warning) but I would leave the text alone and simply disable submitting the data until the user fixes it.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion. For my case, UX requirement is not like your suggestion. Is it possible find out a solution in my described scenario?

Comment: Do you mean in Korean language, when you input a special character (%, $, ..) and called SelectionStart method, it can't work? When I input a '%' character, it could delete it and cursor displayed well. Can you provide how you remove the character and fix the position of cursor?